# Cannot update shared variable across modules that are in while loop between flask server and running background python code

Tags: python, flask, module, global-variables

I have flask server running on my raspberry pi at the same time I'm running python script. There are shared global variable that i need update between the two modules. For example, when I press a button on my flask server, the button function will change a shared variable value (set=0) and my python script that running should react based on the changed values. But i unable to change the shared variable value in main.py because it is in while loop.Let me visualize the what I did

main.py

```
import A

while True:
  if (A.set == 0):
     print "zero"
  else :
    print "one"
```

A.py

```
set = 0
```

flaskweb.py

```
import A
@app.route("/_Mode")
def _Mode():
    state= request.args.get('state')
    if state=="auto":
       A.set = 0
    else:
       A.set = 1
```

I  able to retrieve the data from my flaskserver.py and write them but, it does not change the shared variable value (set) of the main.py because it in the while loop. How do I need to make change where any update i make to the shared variable (set) in flaskweb.py will change the (set) value in my main.py too.Can someone help me how to solve this? I know its very common question . I made lot research in previous forums regarding this but still I cant make it. Your help is needed.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without actually writing the data to a file or database. At least not as you're trying to write it.

Comment: Can you suggest some way hw i cn do it?